# Showing a line in the top of the text after putting the wavy background

Tags: html, css

I've created a wavy background and it looks good, now I need to change the background cause it's just plain. I used the hex `#1F1F1F` so it will turn black also changed the fill property's value to `#1F1F1F` But I think I've made a mistake. Now I see a line at the top of the text. You can just look at the pic.

### No line if I zoom

[image: No underline if i didn't zoom]

### There's a line when you zoom it

[image]

### My code

```css
.centered {
      position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
}

.title {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 38%;
    top: 5%;
    font-size: 55px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



.wave {
    background-image: linear-gradient(144deg, rgba(0,212,255,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 100%);
    min-height: 95vh;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1632563716 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1632563716 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(144% + 1.3px);
    height: 152px;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1632563716 .shape-fill {
    fill: #1F1F1F;
}

/** For mobile devices **/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1632563716 svg {
        width: calc(144% + 1.3px);
        height: 124px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body class="text-white">
    <div class="wave">
      <h1 class="title">Hello World!</h1>
      <p class="centered">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <br />
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
        ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <br />
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
        dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        <br />
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
        officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>

      
<div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1632563716">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M985.66,92.83C906.67,72,823.78,31,743.84,14.19c-82.26-17.34-168.06-16.33-250.45.39-57.84,11.73-114,31.07-172,41.86A600.21,600.21,0,0,1,0,27.35V120H1200V95.8C1132.19,118.92,1055.71,111.31,985.66,92.83Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
    </svg>
</div>


    </div>
    <p class="text-center">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
      doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo
      inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
      <br />
      Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut
      fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem
      sequi nesciunt. <br />
      Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
      consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
      incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
      <br />
      Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
      suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem
      vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil
      molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla
      pariatur?
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you found any solution thanks.

Comment: We can't access the localhost URL as it is for your local server. You should send a codepen or other code snippet form

Answer (score 0):

Set the svg values `viewBox="0 0 1200 118"` and it will be gone.

Comment: didn't work either.

Comment: It works in codepen though. maybe make it a bit more smaller to 115 or 110.

Comment: Maybe it's the problem in the css code...?

Comment: I had once the same problem, so I referred this. https://youtu.be/3owx2vJHkv4 Worked well. You should probably close and reopen the browser after modifying the settings.

Comment: Still doesn't work :/